# Image search from camera with OpenCV and ORB

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, orb

I'm trying to build a simple image search/recognition engine with python and OpenCV. I extract image features this way:

```
alg = cv2.ORB_create()
kps = alg.detect(image)
kps = sorted(kps, key=lambda x: -x.response)[:vector_size]
kps, dsc = alg.compute(image, kps)
dsc = dsc.flatten()
needed_size = (32 * 64)
if dsc.size < needed_size:
dsc = np.concatenate([dsc, np.zeros(needed_size - dsc.size)])
return dsc
```

Then I take a frame from the camera I extract image features the same way and I calculate the Hamming distance. The problem is that if I compare exactly the same image the distance is 0 but I'm not able to search for the image when it is "embedded" in a camera frame. I know that ORB can find objects in a context but I don't know how to use it for this purpose. Anyone with some advice?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the problem. What do you mean by _"embedded"_ _in_ _a_ _camera_ _frame_? Do you have reference frame with features and then you capture frames with the same features but algorithm don't recognize these features?

Comment: Not exactly, for example I extract features from a picture, then I want to recognize the picture printed on paper when "aimed" with a camera. I hope that this clarifies a little bit.